# UWSGI count processes killed with signal 9 (indirectly counting invocations of OOM killer)

Tags: uwsgi

I'm running UWSGI on a server and trying to track when worker processes get OOMed without using `dmesg` since that requires root privileges. In this environment, if a child was killed with `SIGKILL`, it's a safe assumption that the OOM killer did that.

UWSGI reports in its logs what signal a child was killed with. This issue (https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/25) shows an example of logs where a child was reported to have exited with signal 9.

Example:

```
Oct 20 18:54:28 localhost app: DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 16100) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
```

Here's the line of code in UWSGI that's responsible for this message:

```
if (WIFSIGNALED(waitpid_status)) {
    uwsgi_log("DAMN ! worker %d (pid: %d) died, killed by signal %d :( trying respawn ...\n", thewid, (int) diedpid, (int) WTERMSIG(waitpid_status));
}
```

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/65a8d676f3e63a04b07fdcb4e1f92bb6502f024d/core/master.c#L1074

Is there a way to count the number of child processes killed with `SIGKILL` and surface it as a metric within the metric subsystem thing? I'm also wondering whether a child that exceeds the harakiri timeout is counted as being killed with a signal.

UWSGI does seem to keep a per-worker signal count e.g. `"signals": 0`, but  I'm not sure exactly what that field is counting.

Example from same GitHub issue:

`"pid": 11360, 
            "requests": 294, 
            "respawn_count": 38, 
            "rss": 226373632, 
            "running_time": 628263, 
            "signals": 0, 
            "status": "cheap", 
            "tx": 5178, 
            "vsz": 380694528`

Comment: Not a direct answer, but worth considering: The OOM killer is a last-ditch method for the kernel to keep the system running. You cannot rely on it to only target uWSGI workers -- it _will_ eventually kill something that won't come back, like the uWSGI parent or some other important system process. If this is happening regularly, you need to limit the memory usage of uWSGI, run fewer workers, or add more memory.

Comment: @duskwuff ... The nightmare scenario where uWSGI workers (and anything else with a high OOM score) start getting killed is exactly the thing I'm trying to detect so I can get notified and fix the problem. This seems like a reasonable way to distinguish a critical memory shortage from other things without tailing dmesg.